# MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl' which is required to execute 'makeglossaries'

Tags: texstudio, glossaries, miktex2.9

I'm using MiKTeX 2.09 (and TeXstudio) on windows 7.  When I choose the glossary command in TeXstudio to make the glossary, I run into this error:

Process started: makeglossaries.exe "HSFSS"

Sorry, but makeglossaries.exe did not succeed for the following reason: MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl' which is required to execute 'makeglossaries'. Remedy: Make sure 'perl' is installed on your system. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Love\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makeglossaries.log For more information, visit: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-script-engine-not-found

Process exited with error(s)

I tried to run this command on the system prompt:

powershell -Command "& $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/AS701/install-latest.ps1'))) -c'state activate --default youarelove-gmail-com/Perl-5.34.0-Windows'"

but received this error:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>where perl.exe

INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Windows\system32>powershell -Command "& $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object N
et.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/AS701/inst
all-latest.ps1'))) -c'state activate --default youarelove-gmail-com/Perl-5.34.0-
Windows'"
The string starting:
At line:1 char:207

- & $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://
  platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/AS701/install-latest.ps1'))) -c'state activate
  --default youarelove-gmail-com/Perl-5.34.0-Windows <<<< '
  is missing the terminator: '.
  At line:1 char:208
- & $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://
  platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/AS701/install-latest.ps1'))) -c'state activate
  --default youarelove-gmail-com/Perl-5.34.0-Windows' <<<<

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRe
    cordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

C:\Windows\system32>

Not sure where to go from here.  Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Install `https://strawberryperl.com/` on Windows

Comment: @mafsi Issue resolved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Installing https://strawberryperl.com/ resolved my issue.